# Decompose Categorical Attributes in R

Tags: categorical-data, feature-engineering

This seems like it's probably basic, but how do you decompose a categorical variable into its subparts, to then run a regression?  In case that is just mumbo-jumbo, hard example.  I am trying to look at lawsuits filed, which include factors like plaintiff, defendant, filing date, type of law suit etc. The plaintiff category is then classified by country (as the party filing), I want to analyze what countries are filing which kinds of lawsuits.  So instead of running a regression with data$plaintiff as a function of the other factors, I want to make a new variable(I think) that is based on the various factors within the plaintiff category.  I think what I want to do is feature engineering, but I don't understand/cannot figure out how to do this.

I just realized this is basically sort and filter within a column in excel, how do I do that in R?